# Remove list items' property from list in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list like this, I am creating a csv file with below data and I want to exclude some columns, the properties are column names

```
[
 {name: john, age: 25},
 {name: mark, age: 30},
]
```

I want to remove the age property from the list items without any condition just remove the property, so my new list should look like below list and it will be excluded in the csv file

```
[
 {name: john},
 {name: mark},
]
```

Comment: `.Select(t => new {t.name})`?

Comment: Removing means you want delete the  property or hide ?

Comment: It will work but I have 30+ property in one item and i don't want to manually create the item like this so, any better solution?

Comment: I want to remove Aslam

Comment: Looks like a XY-problem. Why do you want to remove the properties? Could you add your existing code?

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
  List<Employee> listEmployee= new List<Employee>([
     {name: john, age: 25},
     {name: mark, age: 30},
    ])
    var reduceAgeFromList= listEmployee.Select(e => new {e.name}).ToList();
```

This way also help you,

```
   public class Employee
    {
        public string name{ get; set; }
    
        [SkipProperty]
        public string age{ get; set; }
    }
    
 List<Employee> employee= new List<Employee>([
     {name: john, age: 25},
     {name: mark, age: 30},
 ])
  var employee.Where(pi => pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SkipPropertyAttribute), true).Length == 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: It will work but I have 30+ property in one item and I don't want to manually create the item like this so, any better solution?

Comment: I think the .Select way was easy and short to use,use Automapper and class also help you to solve the problem. visit: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.md

Answer (score -1):

There are two methods available for fetching data in a list. We can either use lambda expression (or) query using linq.

using linq;

```
  1)  List<details> list= new List<details>()

      var name = list.Where(a => a.name).ToList();  // fetch the data of 
       particular property


  2) var name = from c in list
                 where c.name
                 select c;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).